# Cryptsetup failed

Tags: password, reset

Totally new to Ubuntu here, and I decided to give it a go and do a fresh install on my free-DOS Lenovo e330. Everything went smoothly all the way through the installation, and I decided to add an encryption password to the hard drive.

Now I'm in a situation that I just can't login to Ubuntu. I'm using the password I created for the encryption but there must have been a mistake. Now I can't access the system.

What could I do to reset the password, or just wipe Ubuntu off my SSD? I have no files there so wiping Ubuntu is an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily wipe the newly created system and install again. Before performing *either* of these options it's best to make sure that backups of any important files (that can't easily be replaced) from your computer are current.

**If Ubuntu is the only installed OS** then just boot from the Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB and run the installer again, then tell it to install to the entire disk (overwriting all existing OSes, which happens to be just the Ubuntu system you already installed).

**If Ubuntu is *not* the only installed OS and you want to keep the other OS**, boot from the Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB. Choose *Try Ubuntu without installing* (not *Install Ubuntu*). When you have a usable desktop, run the GParted Partition Editor by pressing the Super (Windows) key or clicking the Ubuntu logo at the upper *left* corner of the screen, and typing `gparted`. You'll see an icon for GParted come up. Click that icon.

Assuming Ubuntu is the only GNU/Linux distribution you have installed, which is probably the case, any `linux-swap` or `ext4` partition belongs to the newly created Ubuntu system. There should be *just one* of *each*. Remove those partitions in GParted. Click the green check mark to apply your changes. Then quit GParted and click Install Ubuntu (it's one of the icons in the launcher). Now install Ubuntu **alongside** the existing operating system to start over.

Comment: Hey!Thanks alot for your help! I tried booting again from my USB but all I get is the GRUB screen, and I can't choose the USB-drive. Is there a command for booting from the USB? How do I gain access to it? Noob talking hehe

Comment: @Abu264 Is it fixed now? Did you successfully reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: no I didn't, as it won't boot Ubuntu from the usb. It goes straight to the grub-screen. Anything I can do ?

Comment: If it booted from the USB flash drive before, then assuming nothing has happened to the USB drive, it should boot now. However, now that there's an OS installed, the OS may boot instead of the USB drive, depending on your boot order. When you *power on* your computer, it should tell you what key or key combination to press for the boot menu, where you should be able to select the external USB drive from among the available boot devices. If it doesn't say anything for that, then it should tell you what key or key combination to press to enter the BIOS setup, where you can change the boot order.

Comment: Yes solved it! Cheers man, appreciate your help, fantastic !